# MySql query: select a list of tag names and for each tag get the most recently tagged albums information

Tags: mysql

I am not quite sure how to write this query of it it can be done in one query. 
Here is the case:

I need to select a list of tag names and for each tag get the most recently tagged albums information. Meaning that if a user creates an album called "Pamela Anderson" and tags that album as "Blondes" then that album is now the most recently tagged album for Blondes. 
There might be 100 albums tagged as "Blondes" but only the most recent one's data should be selected, as determined by the objectTagCreateDate.

The expected data would look like this:

```
    tagId, tagName,   objectTagCreateDate, albumName,       albumPath
   --------------------------------------------------------------------
    1,     Blondes,   2011-08-23,          Pamela Anderson,   7345
    2,     Celebs,    2011-08-20,          Kate Winslet,    2, 5567
    3,     Musicians, 2011-08-22,          Alicia Keys,       6678
```

etc

The tables look like this:

```
Tag
 - tagId
 - tagName

ObjectTag
 - objectType
 - objectId
 - tagId
 - objectTagCreateDate

Album
 - albumId
 - albumName
 - albumPath
```

The join happens on:

```
tag.tagId = objectTag.tagId AND objectTag.objectType = 3 and objectTag.objectId = album.albumId
```

Can this be done in one query and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.tagId, t.tagName, o.objectTagCreateDate, a.albumName, a.albumPath
FROM ObjectTag AS o
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT tagId, MAX(objectTagCreateDate) As MaxDate
            FROM ObjectTag
            WHERE ObjectTag.objectType = 3
            GROUP BY tagId
            ) AS t1
ON t1.tagId = o.tagId AND t1.MaxDate = o.objectTagCreateDate
INNER JOIN Tag AS t ON t1.tagId = t.tagId
INNER JOIN Album AS a ON o.objectID = a.albumId
```

The inner select gets the `MaxDate` per tagId and joins with `ObjectTag`  to get the corresponding `o.objectID`. The rest is just simple joins.

Comment: Thank - this works great. I had to make one small change though, probably a typo. I changed this `ON t1.tagId = o.tagId, t1.MaxDate = o.objectTagCreateDate` to `ON t1.tagId = o.tagId AND t1.MaxDate = o.objectTagCreateDate`  The comma was causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it but I haven´t tested it myself;

```
SELECT T.tagId, T.tagName, MAX(OT.objectTagCreateDate) AS LatestObjectTagCreateDate, A.albumName, A.albumPath
FROM ObjectTag OT
JOIN Tag T ON (T.tagId = OT.tagId)
JOIN Album A ON (A.albumId = OT.objectId AND OT.objectType = 3)
GROUP BY T.tagId
ORDER BY T.tagId
```